# Encoding used when sending emails through singleemail method

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, encoding

When sending out a single email salesforce encodes the HTML body

As per doc : 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setHtmlBody

> **setHtmlBody**(String)
>
> Optional. The HTML version of the email, specified by the sender. ***The
>   value is encoded according to the specification associated with the
>   organization.*** You must specify a value for setTemplateId, setHtmlBody,
>   or setPlainTextBody. Or, you can define both setHtmlBody and
>   setPlainTextBody

Where is this setting in a dev org to control the type of encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is documented under the [Implementation Considerations](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm) by Salesforce:

> The API supports either full Unicode characters or ISO-8859-1
>   characters. The character set for your organization depends on the
>   Salesforce instance your organization uses. If your organization logs
>   into ssl.salesforce.com, then your encoding is ISO-8859-1. All other
>   instances use UTF-8. **You can determine the character set for your
>   organization by calling describeGlobal() and inspecting the encoding
>   value returned in the [DescribeGlobalResult](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal_describeglobalresult.htm#topic-title)**.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have control but you do have visibility?

Comment: I saw that too, but wasn't sure if it was limited to API responses or was system    wide. It wasn't totally clear from that document.

Comment: I went with this coz of this description on the encoding property of the DescribeGlobalResult "Specifies how an organization’s data is encoded" Looks like it represents the encoding for the org's data and not just APIs.